# Hi, i'm trying to develope a chat app using next.js and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, server-side-rendering

My firebase structure is:
-2 Collections: chats and users
-The chats Collection has: users(array) that are in the chat(one to one) and it has other collection named 'messages'
In SSR, i'm trying to get the chat and messages after select a chat.
The function is:

```
export async function getServiceSideProps(context) {
const ref = db.collection("chats").doc(context.query.id);

// PREPARE MESSAGES
const messagesRes = await ref
    .collection("messages")
    .orderBy("timestamp","asc")
    .get();
const messages = messagesRes.docs.map((doc) => ({
    id:doc.id,
    ...doc.data(),
}))
.map((messages) => ({
    ...messages,
    timestamp:messages.timestamp.toDate().getTime(),
}));

//PREPARE THE CHAT
const chatRes = await ref.get();
const chat = {
    id:chatRes.id,
    ...chatRes.data(),
};
return {
    props:{
        messages:JSON.stringify(messages),
        chat:chat,
    },
};
```

}
The Chat componenet is:

```
function Chat({chat,messages}) {
console.log(chat);
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
const recipientUserEmail = chat.users.filter((userFilter) => userFilter !== user.email)[0];
return <div className="container">
    <Head>
        <title>Chat with: {recipientUserEmail}</title>
    </Head>
    <div className="chat">
        <div className="chat__header">
            <div className="chat__header__left">
                <Avatar className="avatar" />
                <div className="header__chatInfo">
                    <h2>test@gmail.com</h2>
                    <p>Last active: 2minutes ago</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="chat__header__right">
                <IconButton>
                    <AttachFileIcon />
                </IconButton>

                <IconButton>
                    <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <SideBar />
</div>
}
```

in the recipientUserEmail's function , when i try to go inside users array it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined.
Any help pls?

Comment: `chat` is undefined. You should be seeing it as such in the log.

Comment: You have a typo: `getServiceSideProps` should be `getServerSideProps`.